# how to set content type csv in apache nifi writer?

Tags: java, apache-nifi

i write a nifi custom processor that handle xlsx to csv , and in my code i generate a string csv like this from xlsx, but i don´t know how to send it as csv, and the other processors like inferavroschema 
 from csv can recognize the inpustream as csv.

```
final AtomicReference<String> value = new AtomicReference<>();

String csvToString= "
name,age,info
javo,23,wasa
pepe,34,lima"

value.set(csvToString);
```

And in my code i send it in this way, but when i see the data provenance it apears as content type text:

```
String results = value.get();
       if(results != null && !results.isEmpty()){
           flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "csv", results);
       }
       flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new OutputStreamCallback() {
           @Override
           public void process(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
               out.write(value.get().getBytes());
           }
       });
       session.transfer(flowFile, SUCCESS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute name for content type in nifi named `mime.type`

So, you have to set its value to `csv`.

```
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "mime.type" "csv");
```